# hide status bar in ios 7

Tags: ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

Hi I have an application but I want to hide the status bar through out the application. Upto ios 6 it works perfectly. But in ios 7 when I open the `ImagePicker` then it shows the status bar and remaining throughout the application. It starts to display only after opening image picker.

What is the reason for this and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

in your apps plist file add a row call it "`View controller-based status bar appearance`" and set it to **NO**.

Add method in your view controller.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
   return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your app's `info.plist`, add a line for `View controller-based status bar appearance` which is a `Boolean`, and set it to `NO`.

---

Have you tried to write the below code in your `-application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` ?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

---

Or you can add this method in your View Controller :

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @user2889249 : I added some details in my Answer. Have you checked that ?